# When to create a new exception type

Tags: .net, exception

When is it justified to create a new exception. Is there some kind of checklist with conditions to be met before it is a good design decision to make a new exception type with respects to the .Net framework?

For example consider:

You have a class with a method that return an integer that is not critical to be completed by the consumer of the method but provide some extra information. There are various things that could go wrong in the method that does not depend on how the user of the class calls this method. Let say one is that network connection could be lost and the other is that the API of the web service the method is trying to call changed. The consumer of the method do not have the ability to handle these cases differently to try recover from the exception. Should there be two different exceptions for these operations or a more general exception (say for example `CommunicationFailureException`) covering both these cases with a specific description and inner exception? Or should the .Net exceptions be thrown that was originally thrown when the method failed to call into the web service?

I would appreciate more to know the principles for creating a new exception type rather than something to just cover this specific example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new exception type when you have something additional to say about the exception - something that is not covered by the existing exceptions.

If your application has some specific invariants and you need to communicate they are invalid - that may be a good place for a custom exception type. This allows you to catch exceptions that are specific to your application.

Comment: @Brady -  Nope, you were 15 seconds after me... (hover over the time and see the UTC timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to create custom exceptions in two cases.

1. If you need to add more information to the exception.
2. If there is a possibility that the caller of your exception will need to catch that particular exception and handle it differently.

Otherwise, it's best to use the standard exception classes.

Comment: Number 2 is the real reason to create a custom exception type. Number 1 is irrelevant unless number 2 is also true.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html?page=2) give some very good pointers.

Especially the section that states:

> Try not to create new custom exceptions if they do not have useful
>   information for client code.

Comment: Please post at least a summary. A link is not an answer.

Comment: @Oded, ok, I'll repeat some of what it mentions

Answer (score 0):

You can check this page for a small checklist: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/creating.html

This site is for Java, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Links are not answers. Please post a summary at a minimum.

Comment: The linked page already contains a very short description. So should I duplicate the information here.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net Framework does not provide any means by which a routine that calls method `Foo` can distinguish an exception that was thrown by `Foo`, from one which was thrown by method called `Foo` in a fashion that `Foo` didn't expect and didn't handle.  The `StackTrace` may provide clues, but because of optimizations like in-lining it's not entirely reliable.

Consequently, if `Foo` is going to throw any exception which is supposed to have some meaning to its caller, it should ensure that any exception of that type which escapes will in fact have that meaning.  Note that the .Net Framework is somewhat deficient in this regard; for example, the definition for `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` indicates that `InvalidOperationException` is supposed to be thrown if the collection is modified during enumeration (suggesting in some cases that code might want to make a copy of the collection and enumerate that), but doesn't make clear what should happen if a routine called from `MoveNext()` throws such an exception for some other reason.

Using a custom exception is often a good way to avoid such issues.  If you throw an exception from your routine of a type which will not get thrown for any other purpose, code which catches it can be certain that the exception means what it thinks it means.

Answer (score 0):

Oded made a good point.

What I think can be added in this topic is an abstraction to the API. You need to create an exception wrapper that would provide common contract for all implementations. I'm aware that it is covered by oded's response but I thought it can be pointed out:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        IUserRepository = //assume that IoC container provides specific implementation
    }
    catch (UserNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("User not found: {0}", e.Id));
    }
}


class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

class UserNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public int Id {get;private set;}

    public UserNotFoundException(int id, Exception innerException)
        :base(string.Format("User {0} could not be found", id), innerException)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUser(int id);
}

class XmlUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    string _path;

    public XmlUserRepository(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            //retrieving code that might throw IOException or XmlException
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //catching Exception is not a good thing to do, but for the sake of clarity I made this like that
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id, e);
        }
    }
}

class DbUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    string _dbConnectionString;

    public DbUserRepository(string dbConnectionString)
    {
        _dbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    }

    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            //retrieving code that might throw SqlException
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //catching Exception is not a good thing to do, but for the sake of clarity I made this like that
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id, e);
        }
    }
}
```